# Finding the owner of a file or directory on the system in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, swift2

How can I find out who is the owner of a file or directory in Swift? I know the NSFileOwnerAccountName does the trick, but I can't find how to use it.

Goal is to create an if/else clause. If the owner is a certain name, proceed. If not, don't.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not focusing much on code with String(NSStrings ) and AnyObjects what i wrote is

```
var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager();
var documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

let destinationPath:NSString = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/48630772.pdf")
var username : String = " ";
if(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationPath as String))
{

    var attributes = try fileManager.attributesOfItemAtPath(destinationPath as String)

    username = attributes[NSFileOwnerAccountName] as! String
    print(username)

}
```

Now you can check against the string value of Username

Comment: Thanks! This is great and works, but only for documents within the domain. What if I needed to check the owner of e.g. /usr/local though?

Comment: Use NSOpenStepRootDirectory() like                                                            var documentsPath = NSOpenStepRootDirectory() and than let destinationPath:NSString = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/usr/local")